# Tooltip shows with Standard Tooltip

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, font-awesome-5

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<span class='fas fa-print' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Print'>Printing</span>
```

In this code, the `span` has a `tooltip` toggle, When I hover over it,

It shows me the `Bootstrap Tooltip` then shows the `Standard Tooltip` after it directly, b

eing both of them shown, What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @ZimSystem Both Firefox and Chrome latest versions, Also fiddle doesn't show it on Chrome with the tooltip of bootstrap, But in browser itself it occurs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the font-awesome svg is messing it up. Wrap the icon in a separate span for the tooltip...

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Print">
   <span class="fas fa-print">Printing</span>
</span>
```